# Selecting an instance to proceed with

Tags: java, instance, selection

Somehow I try to make a user selection of which cook has to prepare the food. I already created the variable `whichcook` and place that where `cook1` used to stay. But I don't know how to carry on. I want to let the user select between either "Jan de Vries" or "SinBad" to prepare. So the methode `deliverer.delivered(whichcook, customer);` carries on with the selected name. I figure if have to use `instanceof` I guess, but don't know how to really do that. I know how to make a user-input and cases etc that's not the problem. It's more about how to isolate the right instance!!
Someone a key suggestion???

```
java

package KebabStore;

public class DamascusKebab 

{

    public static int cooksnumber;
    public static int deliverersnumber;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Cook cook1      = new Cook ("Jan de Vries", "Butcherknife 1", "1212-IS", "Allahmelo", 123456);
        Cook cook2      = new Cook ("Sinbad", "Camelhumb 2","2323-IS", "Halal-lem", 654321);

        Deliverer deliverer1 = new Deliverer ("Ali Baba", "Helmgras 11", "3434-JH", "Ji-Hattem",456789);
        Deliverer deliverer2 = new Deliverer ("Muammar", "Zadeldreef 22", "4545-JH", "Moskemenade", 987654);


        Customer customer    = new Customer ("Piet Hein", "Klantlaan 25", "5656-KL", "Darmstadt");


        cooksnumber = Cook.numberofcooks;
        deliverersnumber = Deliverer.numberofdeliverers;



        Cook whichcook = cook1;

        deliverer.delivered(whichcook, customer);

    }


}
```

Comment: Why not let the user enter either `1` or `2` to indicate his/her choice of cook;  if he chooses `1`, set `whichcook = cook1;`, if he chooses 2, set `whichcook = cook2;`, if he enters any other choice, keep asking until he enters 1 or 2.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson. Yeah I was considering that. But imagine there are hundreds of entries for cook? Still, I want to know how to let Java look for the right instance that meets the name "Jan de Vries" for instance...and so the program carries on with that particular instance, represented by the variable `whichcook`

Comment: Enter all your `Cook` instances into a `Map<String, Cook>` with their names as the keys.  Let the user enter a name, and look up the corresponding `Cook` instance in the `Map` using the user's entry as the search key.

Comment: @KevinAnderson thanks. I'll try and see how I'll get there!!

Answer (score 0):

How are going to get the user input?

if it's from the Scanner

```
Cook whichcook;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int choice = scanner.nextInt()

if (choice == 1)
    whichcook = cook1;
else
    whichcook = cook2;

deliverer.delivered(whichcook, customer);
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand this solution.  But I prefer more the entry of a name above to of a number. Looking to the number of viewers, I bet either it's not possible how I want it or, it's very complicated and usual to want.